# Pandas Column containing a list of matched strings found using str.contains('|'.join(words))

Tags: python, pandas

I have string data that I am matching to a list of terms and I want to create a new column that shows all words found in each row of the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'String': ['Cat Dog Fish', 'Cat Dog', 'Pig Horse', 'DogFish']})
print(df)

         String
0  Cat Dog Fish
1       Cat Dog
2     Pig Horse
3       DogFish
4      CatHorse

words = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Fish']
```

I know using `df.loc[df['String'].str.contains('|'.join(words))].copy()` will return all rows that contain at least one of the terms I'm searching for but I would like output that keeps a record of which terms are found in each string like this:

```
         String           Matched
0  Cat Dog Fish  [Cat, Dog, Fish]
1       Cat Dog        [Cat, Dog]
2       DogFish       [Dog, Fish]
3      CatHorse             [Cat]
```

or even just

```
         String     Matched
0  Cat Dog Fish  CatDogFish
1       Cat Dog      CatDog
2       DogFish     DogFish
3      CatHorse         Cat
```

Not sure where to begin with making this column, any help is appreciated

Comment: How many items do you have in your word list?

Comment: @mozway in my actual use case there are currently 11 terms, but this list will likely expand as I understand my raw data better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
words = ["Cat", "Dog", "Fish"]

df["Matched"] = df["String"].apply(lambda s: [w for w in words if w in s])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         String           Matched
0  Cat Dog Fish  [Cat, Dog, Fish]
1       Cat Dog        [Cat, Dog]
2     Pig Horse                []
3       DogFish       [Dog, Fish]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html):

```
df['Matched'] = df['String'].str.findall('|'.join(words))

         String           Matched
0  Cat Dog Fish  [Cat, Dog, Fish]
1       Cat Dog        [Cat, Dog]
2     Pig Horse                []
3       DogFish       [Dog, Fish]
```